# Creating an algorithm for distributing unique items

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm not sure how to create an algorithm for a specific problem in my code, so I created this puzzle

- There are 3 cookie monsters.
- Each monster has a bag with a random number of cookies from 0 to a finite number (let's say 100).
- There are many different types of cookies, but we don't know how many (we can find out after generating the cookies).
- Each monster is going to eat 1 cookie from it's own bag

  - None of the other monsters can get a cookie of the same type.
  - If two or more monsters don't have any unique flavours in their bag, the monster at the lower index should get to pick the cookie and the other(s) don't get a cookie.
- We want to make sure that every monster gets a cookie if possible.

.

```
// A cookie maker for good measure:
function cookieMaker(quant) {
  // Fill in your own flavours...
  const flavours = [...]
  const cookies = []
  for(let i = 0; i < quant; i++) {
    cookies.push(flavours[Math.floor(Math.random() * flavours.length)])
  }
  return cookies
}

// This is our function
function pickCookies(monsters) {
  ...
}

pickCookies([
  {
    name: 'Fluffy',
    cookies: ['choco', 'vanilla', 'blueberry']
  },
  {
    name: 'Pillowpants',
    cookies: ['choco', 'vanilla']
  },
  {
    name: 'Pinky',
    cookies: ['choco']
  }
])

// Should return:
[
  {
    name: 'Fluffy',
    eat: 'blueberry'
  },
  {
    name: 'Pillowpants',
    eat: 'vanilla'
  },
  {
    name: 'Pinky',
    eat: 'choco'
  }
]

// Note, that it should also work if you shuffle the list.
```

I made a [list of flavours](https://cdn.rawgit.com/demux/ad32c612b303aa12d1cdf043225fa1d2/raw/3a037fb7ad30d8a383526ebc62b3671a1656c06d/flavours.json) for you in json format:

How would you solve this puzzle?

### Revisions

I seem to have left out at least one detail, so in case you already started working on it, I'll add any changes to the puzzle here as to not confuse anyone by changing the rules suddenly:

- **#1** The monsters should try to get a cookie from the top of the bag (lower array index), if possible.

Comment: So if monster A eats a type X, can monster B ever eat a type X? Or are two monsters only prevented from eating a cookie of the same type on the same iteration? Do the monsters continue eating until all cookies have been consumed?

Comment: Each monster only eats one cookie. 1 iteration. But if want to solve more problems, go ahead :p

Comment: So it's possible that only 1 cookie is eaten if each monster draws a cookie of type X ?

Comment: @naomik Yes, it is, the first monster in the list should get cookie X.

Comment: Lastly, `We want to make sure that every monster gets a cookie if possible.` can you explain a little more on this then? If each monster draws a type X, would monster B and C draw the next cookie looking for a unique cookie type ?

Comment: @naomik, Yes, but if monster A has a unique flavour in it's bag which B and C don't have, but B and C only have X, then A should get a new flavour and B should get X

Comment: @demux There is a simplification you can do to make the problem slightly smaller sometimes, which would happen to completely solve the example in your post, but wouldn't solve the problem in general: Create a reverse map (from cookie types to an array of monsters that have that cookie type in their bag). While there is only one monster for a specific cookie type, declare that monster to eat that type and remove that monster from each of the cookie type's monster arrays.

Comment: @Paulpro If you'd elaborate on that in an answer, I would give it an upvote. Maybe it would help me get to the solution of the problem in general.

Comment: I would be tempted approach this like a least cost search where your cost function is the number of unique elements out of all elements. For instance, the cost of blueberry in your example would be .16, vanilla would be .33, and choco is 0.5. Which should lead you to the correction solution if it exists.

Comment: I'm going to bed soon, so I hope everything is clear. If anyone has any ideas on how I could improve the quality of the question, please let me know or suggest an edit. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

I find your question interesting, so I gave it a shot by creating this algorithm:

## In words

1. For each monster, create an Array containing all cookie types in their bag (remove duplicates).
2. For each monster, count their choices (flavors available).
3. Take the monster with the smallest number of options.
4. For each option, check how many other monsters share this flavor.
5. Take the flavor with the smallest number of owners, and make the monster eat it.
6. Remove that flavor from the remaining monsters' bags.
7. Repeat from step 2 until [there are no other hungry monsters left] OR [every monster left has no more flavors available].

## In code

**First shot**

```js
var monsters = [{name:'Fluffy'}, {name:'Pillowpants'}, {name:'Pinky'}],
    flavors = ['choco', 'vanilla', 'blueberry', 'peanut butter'],
    maxNumberOfCookies = 6;

$('#generateBtn').click(generateExample);
generateExample();

function generateExample() {
  // Fill each monster's bag
  for(var i=0; i<monsters.length; i++) monsters[i].cookies = cookieMaker();
  // 3, 2, 1, bon appetit!
  var res = pickCookies(monsters);
  displayResults(monsters, res);
}

function cookieMaker() {
  var cookies = [],
      // The quantity is random for each monster
      quant = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNumberOfCookies);
  for(var i=0; i<quant; i++) {
    cookies.push(flavors[Math.floor(Math.random() * flavors.length)])
  }
  return cookies;
}

function pickCookies(monsters) {
  var res = [];
  // List flavors available for each monster
  for(var i=0; i<monsters.length; i++) {
    var m = monsters[i],
        flavorsInBag = [];
    for(var j=0; j<m.cookies.length; j++) {
      if(flavorsInBag.indexOf(m.cookies[j]) < 0) {
        flavorsInBag.push(m.cookies[j]);
      }
    }
    res.push({name: m.name, flavors: flavorsInBag, eat: false});
  }

  while(!allMonstersAte(res) && !noMoreFlavors(res)) {
    // Take the monster with the smallest number of options
    var monsterWithLeastFlavors = false;
    for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
      if(!res[i].flavors.length) continue;
      if(!monsterWithLeastFlavors
      || res[i].flavors.length < monsterWithLeastFlavors.flavors.length) {
        monsterWithLeastFlavors = res[i];
      }
    }
    // Select the flavor owned by the fewest monsters
    var flavorWithLeastOwners = monsterWithLeastFlavors.flavors[0],
        fewestNbOfOwners = res.length;
    for(var i=0; i<monsterWithLeastFlavors.flavors.length; i++) {
      var nbOfOwners = getNbOfOwners(monsterWithLeastFlavors.flavors[i], res);
      if(nbOfOwners < fewestNbOfOwners) {
        flavorWithLeastOwners = monsterWithLeastFlavors.flavors[i];
        fewestNbOfOwners = nbOfOwners;
      }
    }
    makeMonsterEat(monsterWithLeastFlavors, flavorWithLeastOwners, res);
  }
  return res;
}

// Returns true if all monsters have a property "eat" != false
function allMonstersAte(res) {
  return !res.some(function(monster){ return !monster.eat; });
}

// Returns true if all monsters have no flavor left to choose from
function noMoreFlavors(res) {
  return !res.some(function(monster){ return monster.flavors.length; });
}

// Returns the number of monsters who have that flavor
function getNbOfOwners(flavor, monsters) {
  return monsters.filter(function(monster){
    monster.flavors.indexOf(flavor)>-1;
  }).length;
}

function makeMonsterEat(monster, flavor, res) {
  monster.flavors = [];
  monster.eat = flavor;
  for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
    res[i].flavors = res[i].flavors.filter(function(fl){ return fl != flavor; });
  }
}

function displayResults(monsters, res) {
  var initial = "";
  for(var i=0; i<monsters.length; i++) {
    initial += '<b>' + monsters[i].name + '\'s bag contains:</b> '
             + (monsters[i].cookies.length ? monsters[i].cookies.join(', ') : '<span style="color:red">NOTHING</span>') + '<br>';
  }
  var result = "";
  for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
    result += '<b>' + res[i].name + ' ate:</b> '
            + (res[i].eat ? res[i].eat : '<span style="color:red">NOTHING</span>')
            + '<br>';
  }
  $('#result').html('<h2>Initial state</h2>'
                    + initial
                    + '<h2>Result</h2>'
                    + result
                   );
}
```

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0}
body{font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding: 1em; font-size: 14px}
h2{font-size: 18px; margin: .3em 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="generateBtn">Generate new example</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**More functional approach**

I don't know if that's what you wanted, but I tried...

```js
var monsters = [{name:'Fluffy'}, {name:'Pillowpants'}, {name:'Pinky'}],
    flavors = ['choco', 'vanilla', 'blueberry', 'peanut butter'],
    maxNumberOfCookies = 6;

$.getJSON('https://cdn.rawgit.com/demux/ad32c612b303aa12d1cdf043225fa1d2/raw/3a037fb7ad30d8a383526ebc62b3671a1656c06d/flavours.json')
  .done(init);

function init(data) {
  flavors = data;
  $('body').html('<button id="generateBtn">Generate new example</button><div id="result"></div>');
  $('#generateBtn').click(generateExample);
  generateExample();
}

function generateExample() {
  // Fill each monster's bag
  for (var i = 0; i < monsters.length; i++)
    monsters[i].cookies = cookieMaker(Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNumberOfCookies));
  // 3, 2, 1, bon appetit!
  var res = pickCookies(monsters);
  displayResults(monsters, res);
}

function cookieMaker(quant) {
  var cookies = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < quant; i++) {
    cookies.push(flavors[Math.floor(Math.random() * flavors.length)])
  }
  return cookies;
}

/*
 * Returns a new Array of monsters who ate unique cookies
 */
function pickCookies(monsters) {
  var res = getMonstersWithFlavors(monsters);

  while (!allMonstersAte(res) && !noMoreFlavors(res)) {
    var monsterIndex = indexOfMonsterWithLeastFlavors(res),
      flavor = flavorWithLeastOwners(res[monsterIndex].flavors, res);

    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
      if (i == monsterIndex) res[i] = makeMonsterEat(res[i], flavor);
      else res[i] = removeFlavor(res[i], flavor);
    }
  }

  return res;
}

/*
 * Returns a new Array of monsters with their flavors
 */
function getMonstersWithFlavors(monsters) {
  return monsters.map(function(monster) {
    return {
      name: monster.name,
      flavors: removeDuplicates(monster.cookies),
      eat: false
    };
  });
}

/*
 * Returns a new Array without duplicates
 */
function removeDuplicates(arr) {
  return Array.from(new Set(arr));
}

/*
 * Returns the index of the monster with least flavors
 */
function indexOfMonsterWithLeastFlavors(monsters) {
  var tmp = { monsterIndex: -1, count: false };
  for (var i = 0; i < monsters.length; i++) {
    if (!monsters[i].flavors.length) continue;
    if (!tmp.count || monsters[i].flavors.length < tmp.count) {
      tmp = { monsterIndex: i, count: monsters[i].flavors.length };
    }
  }
  return tmp.monsterIndex;
}

/*
 * Returns the flavor owned by least monsters
 */
function flavorWithLeastOwners(flavors, monsters) {
  var tmp = { flavor: '', count: false };
  for (var i = 0; i < flavors.length; i++) {
    var nbOfOwners = getNbOfOwners(flavors[i], monsters);
    if (!tmp.count || nbOfOwners < tmp.count) {
      tmp = { flavor: flavors[i], count: nbOfOwners };
    }
  }
  return tmp.flavor;
}

/*
 * Checks if all monsters have a property "eat" != false
 */
function allMonstersAte(res) {
  return !res.some(function(monster) {
    return !monster.eat;
  });
}

/*
 * Checks if all monsters have no flavor left to choose from
 */
function noMoreFlavors(res) {
  return !res.some(function(monster) {
    return monster.flavors.length;
  });
}

/*
 * Returns the number of monsters who have that flavor
 */
function getNbOfOwners(flavor, monsters) {
  return monsters.filter(function(monster) {
    monster.flavors.indexOf(flavor) > -1;
  }).length;
}

/*
 * Returns a new monster Object with the cookie they ate
 */
function makeMonsterEat(monster, flavor) {
  return {
    name: monster.name,
    flavors: [],
    eat: flavor
  };
}

/*
 * Returns a new monster Object without the cookie flavor
 */
function removeFlavor(monster, flavor) {
  return {
    name: monster.name,
    flavors: monster.flavors.filter(function(fl) {
      return fl != flavor
    }),
    eat: monster.eat
  };
}


function displayResults(monsters, res) {
  var initial = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < monsters.length; i++) {
    initial += '<b>' + monsters[i].name + '\'s bag contains:</b> ' +
      (monsters[i].cookies.length ? monsters[i].cookies.join(', ') : '<span style="color:red">NOTHING</span>') + '<br>';
  }
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    result += '<b>' + res[i].name + ' ate:</b> ' +
      (res[i].eat ? res[i].eat : '<span style="color:red">NOTHING</span>') +
      '<br>';
  }
  $('#result').html('<h2>Initial state</h2>' +
    initial +
    '<h2>Result</h2>' +
    result
  );
}
```

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0}
body{font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding: 1em; font-size: 14px}
h2{font-size: 18px; margin: .3em 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Loading...</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be doing the job. I'll review this tomorrow. Extra challenge if you're up for it: Do you think you can do this using with a more functional approach? i.e. fewer mutable variables and each function has one specific task / is "pure" - takes input and returns output.

Comment: We should also see what happens with more flavours, even though the edge case of having relatively few flavours is the one we're focusing on. `$.json('https://cdn.rawgit.com/demux/ad32c612b303aa12d1cdf043225fa1d2/raw/3a037fb7ad30d8a383526ebc62b3671a1656c06d/flavours.json')`

Comment: @demux I don't know if that's really what you wanted, but I've tried my best :)

Comment: It's just something I've been aiming for in my own coding. It's good practice :)

Comment: +1, this is a good greedy approximation algorithm. It should work in most random cases, especially when the number of cookie types is much larger than the number of monsters. It will fail in most random cases where the number of cookies and monsters are very close to each other and very large, and in smaller contrived cases like the one in my answer, but in general it should do quite well and may be good enough for the OPs problem.

Comment: You could also turn this into a backtracking algorithm, where if it finds a monster that can't eat anything it undoes a previous decision and then tries to eat the cookie with the second fewestNbOfOwners instead, or third fewestNbOfOwners and so-on. That would make it deterministically find a solution if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is called "A System of Distinct Representatives" and there are a few theorems about them and at least a couple of published algorithms for solving it. You may find [Hall's Marriage Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem) interesting. To summarize it in context:

> If, and only if, for every subset of monsters there are more distinct types of cookies in those monsters' bags then there are monsters in the subset, it is possible for every monster to eat a cookie.

@blex wrote an algorithm that is a good greedy approximation algorithm. It should always work when the number of possible cookie types is much larger than the number of monsters, but will usually fail when those numbers are very close to each other and also very large.

Below is a contrived example where @blex's algorithm fails with eight monsters and eight distinct cookie types. Right away, Blubite makes the wrong choice, he must choose vanilla, but he chooses choco and with that choice there is no possible solution, since Fluffy, Fred, Jub, and Pillowpants are a subset of four monsters with only three choices between them (oatmeal, blueberry, and peanut butter).

## **Initial state**

Blubite's bag contains: choco, vanilla
Fluffy's bag contains: choco, blueberry, peanut butter
Fred's bag contains: oatmeal, blueberry, peanut butter
Jub's bag contains: oatmeal, blueberry, peanut butter
Pillowpants's bag contains: oatmeal, blueberry, peanut butter
Pinky's bag contains: vanilla, oatmeal, sugar, rum, green
Scuzzy's bag contains: vanilla, oatmeal, sugar, rum, green
Ziffu's bag contains: vanilla, oatmeal, sugar, rum, green

## @blex algorithm

Blubite ate: choco
Fluffy ate: blueberry
Fred ate: oatmeal
Jub ate: peanut butter
Pillowpants ate: **NOTHING**
Pinky ate: vanilla
Scuzzy ate: sugar
Ziffu ate: rum

## Real solution

Blubite ate: vanilla
Fluffy ate: choco
Fred ate: oatmeal
Jub ate: blueberry
Pillowpants ate: peanut butter
Pinky ate: sugar
Scuzzy ate: rum
Ziffu ate: green

There is [a book containing two algorithms](https://books.google.ca/books?id=VyA4AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=An+algorithm+for+distinct+representatives.&source=bl&ots=jfgEI2wXM1&sig=8i4brmOQOq25ZfOudJ0KJzAvUNQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFi-uI6MPOAhUT12MKHSDyAAoQ6AEIWDAJ#v=onepage&q=An%20algorithm%20for%20distinct%20representatives.&f=false) for solving it correctly in the general case, and here is [an academic paper](http://opensample.info/an-algorithm-for-distinct-representatives), from 1956 with the original description of one of those two algorithms. I don't intend to implement the algorithm in JavaScript, but I may revisit this later if I need a break.

Comment: Thank you, this is very interesting. Clearly I have some reading to do! :D